# String as immutable object

Tags: java, string

If String is a immutable object then is it possible to revert the changed values back?
What i mean is that if there is one string variable

```
String str="Hello";
```

and if it is changed to

```
str="Hi!";
```

Now, as we know that it will create two string objects "Hello" and "Hi!" and at present str points "Hi!". So what i am asking is that is it possible to assign reference of string "Hello"  **(the previous one, not by creating new)** to **str** as it is present somewhere in the memory?

Comment: yes, just use a temporary variable.

Comment: (Also, might worth to mention the string interning feature works almost like a magic temp variable for strings in memory)

Comment: no, without using temp object. I mean like using undo in Notepad.

Comment: @PrathameshDeshmukh: Then the answer is: no, Java does not have a built-in way to undo variable assignments.

Comment: If I'm not missing ayour point and you need to implement undo/redo in your app, you can take a look at the command pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: @PrathameshDeshmukh - you cannot undo it. Once you have assigned a new string value to your str.. you're actually changing the old reference to the new reference.

Comment: The only way java could implement this, is if behind the scenes it kept temp objects for every variable that you've reassigned. This is vastly wasteful. If you have something you need to get back, simply save a temp for THAT object.

Comment: The String wasn't changed.  The *pointer* (er, "reference") was changed to address a different String.  And there's no way to "undo" that.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  It appears that the most obvious thing to do is what you have asked, so I must assume you haven't told us what the real issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Java uses a String pool. So if you do:

```
String str = "abc";
str = "def";
str = "abc";
```

`str` will now point back to the original "abc" from the beginning.

However, if you use `new` Strings, you can force them to be the same by calling the `intern` method of String. This method will assure you that the returned String is in the shared String pool in memory.

```
String str1 = new String("abc").intern();
String str2 = new String("abc").intern();
```

Now, `str1 == str2`, which means that they point to the same String object.

---

To answer the question if you can undo an assignment: **no**. Your question was about Strings, but the same idea applies for everything.

```
int k = 4;
k = 9;
// now reverting to the "previous value" is impossible without hardcoding 4 again
k = 4;
```

You might think that it is different when you are using Strings, but it is not. The only difference is that a String *object*  is somewhere in memory and that an int is only 4 bytes in memory.

Comment: it does this because java's vm keeps string values around even after a reference has changed. This is so it can re-use strings. so, in your example: `str = "someNewString;` isn't creating a new string if it exists, it setting a reference to that string in memory.

Comment: yeah, that is obvious but what i mean is reverting back into old state like undo.

Comment: I'm not sure I can agree with your first statement. Java keeps String objects in the String pool if they where hard coded and could be placed in the string pool at compile time. Creating new String objects doesn't keep these objects in memory for ever.

Comment: Strings in the "string pool" are only guaranteed to persist as long as there is at least one reference to them.  String literals are referenced from the classes that contain them, and hence will hang around as long as the classes do (which usually is until the end of time).

Answer (score 1):

You can do

`str = "Hello"`

JVM tries to look for the `String` `Hello` in its `String pool` if it finds it will reassign your variable `str` to `Hello`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, When a `String` is created is placed in handled memory string pool,In this case, JVM searches the string pool to see if equivalent string exist already. if yes, returns the reference to same. if not, adds it to string pool and returns the reference. So a new object may be created OR may not be.

Answer (score 1):

when you do `str = "Hi";` , the first value of str is overriden and is not present in the RAM.
if you want to preserve its value , you need to store it in temporary variable :

```
String str = "Hello";
String temp = str;//store Hello in temporary variable
str = "Hi!" ;
str = temp ; //first value is back
```

You can also , Use `Arraylist<String>` like a history or archive of the previous values.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code creates zero objects. All string literals are created at class loading time, before any code execution happens.
2. Wherever you use the same string literal in code, you refer to one and the same object. Therefore it is very easy to refer again to your `"Hello"` string at any point.

Answer (score 0):

As the String "Hello" is still in the String Pool, and will be there for a while, you can reference any variable to it:

```
str = "Hello";
str = "Hi";
String s = "Hello"; //its the same Hello as the first one
```

The only case where you won't reference the same string is i you do

```
String s = New String ("Hello"); //this will be a different "Hello" from the first one.
```